# SignalR. Timer is not stopping on the server

Tags: signalr

We are using SignalR for information exchange.

When the web browser is connected a timer starts, but it is not stopping when user close the browser.
Here is the code. `starttimer` function runs when browser connected.
When user disconnect the browser, timer still running on the server.

```
[HubName("myChatHub")]
public class InboundCallsDataShare : Hub
{
    private OverrideTimer timer ;
    private List<GroupNConnectionId> groupsList = new List<GroupNConnectionId>();
    public void send(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(message);
        //Clients..addMessage(message);

    }

    public void starttimer(string queue)
    {
        //var connectionId = this.Context.ConnectionId;
        //GroupNConnectionId objGroupNConnectionId=new GroupNConnectionId();
        //objGroupNConnectionId.Group = queue;
        //objGroupNConnectionId.ConnectionID = connectionId;
        //if(groupsList.Contains(objGroupNConnectionId))return;
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //groupsList.Add(objGroupNConnectionId);
        Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, queue);
        timer = new OverrideTimer(queue);
        timer.Interval = 15000;
        timer.Elapsed +=new EventHandler<BtElapsedEventArgs>(timer_Elapsed);
        //first time call
        timer_Elapsed(timer,new BtElapsedEventArgs(){Queue = queue});
        //ends
        timer.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Timer for queue " +queue);
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
       return base.OnConnected();
    }
    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {

        //timer.Stop();
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }



    public void getdatafromxml(string queue)
    {

        string list = (new Random()).Next(1, 10000).ToString();
        Clients.All.getList(list);

        //Clients..addMessage(message);

    }
    public ICBMObject GetInterationList(string queue)
    {
        //ININInterations.QueueListViewItemData _obj = new ININInterations.QueueListViewItemData();
        return GetInboundCallCountFromXML(queue);
        //return _obj.MainFunctionIB();

    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, BtElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        ICBMObject objICBMObject = GetInboundCallCountFromXML(e.Queue);
        Clients.Group(e.Queue).getList(objICBMObject);
        CreateFile(e.Queue);
        //Clients.All.getList(objICBMObject);
    }

    private void CreateFile(string queue)
    {
        string path = @"D:\t.txt";
        string text = File.ReadAllText(path);
        text += queue+ DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        File.WriteAllText(path, text);
    }
    public ICBMObject GetInboundCallCountFromXML(string queue)
    {
        FileStream fs = null;
        int totalInboundCalls = 0,
                totalInboundCallsUnassigned = 0;
        string longestDuration = "";
        bool updateText = false;
        try
        {
            XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            XmlNodeList xmlnode;
            int i = 0;
            string str = null;
            fs = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "InboundXML/" + queue + ".xml",
                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            if (fs.CanRead)
            {
                xmldoc.Load(fs);
                xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName(queue);

                for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
                {

                    totalInboundCalls = Convert.ToInt32(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim());
                    totalInboundCallsUnassigned = Convert.ToInt32(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText.Trim());
                    longestDuration = xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim();

                }
                updateText = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


        }
        finally
        {
            if (fs != null)
            {
                fs.Close();
                fs.Dispose();
            }
        }


        return new ICBMObject()
        {
            TotalInboundCalls = totalInboundCalls,
            TotalInboundCallsUnassigned = totalInboundCallsUnassigned,
            LongestDuration = longestDuration,
            UpdateText = updateText
            //string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
            //    _LongetInbound.Hours,
            //    _LongetInbound.Minutes,
            //    _LongetInbound.Seconds)
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: CreateFile(e.Queue); is executing after 15 seconds which is not required..

Comment: do you call disconnect on client side when you detect the window or tab is closing?

Comment: No i have not called any function on disconnect from client side. But server side we have public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        if(timer!=null)
        timer.Dispose();
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }

Comment: You need to call disconnect on the client side if you want that method to fire, or to wait for the preconfigured connection timeout time. Read [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events). It's a bit lengthy but it's absolutely a must read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the fact that its commented out? Did you put a break point on the timer to see if its getting hit at all? It might be that there is a delay in calling the onDisconnect, if the timeout property is set too large, it might not fire. it might be entering onReconnected if it does not know the client is closed.

Comment: The sequence of events described here is not guaranteed. SignalR makes every attempt to raise connection lifetime events in a predictable manner according to this scheme, but there are many variations of network events and many ways in which underlying communications frameworks such as transport APIs handle them. For example, the Reconnected event might not be raised when the client reconnects, or the OnConnected handler on the server might run when the attempt to establish a connection is unsuccessful. This describes the effects that would normally be produced by certain typical circumstances

Comment: just for reference